# Perl Dancer2 infinite-loop on get when calling a method

Tags: perl, infinite-loop, dancer

I made a photobooth with Dancer some years ago and it worked fine.
Now I try to move this to Dancer2. However, It's not working anymore, because I have some infinite-loop.

Let's say my app looks like this:

```
package App;
use Dancer2;

# Photobox is my pm file with all the magic
use Photobox;

my $photobox = photobox->new();

get '/photo' => sub {
    my $photo;

    # Trigger cam and download photo. It returns me the filename of the photo.
    $photo = $photobox->takePicture();

    # Template photo is to show the photo
    template 'photo',
    {
        'photo_filename' => $photo,
        'redirect_uri' => "someURI"
    };        
}
```

`takePicture()` looks like this:

```
sub takePicture {

    my $Objekt = shift;
    my $return;
    my $capture;

    $return = `gphoto2 --auto-detect`;

    if ($return =~ m/usb:/) {
            $capture = `gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename=$photoPath$filename`;

        if (!-e $photoPath.$filename) {
            return "no-photo-error.png";
        }
        else {
            return $filename;
        }   
    } else {
      die "Camera not found: $return";
    }
}
```

When I now call `/photo`, it'll result in an infinite loop. The browser is *"frefreshing"* all the time and my cam is shooting one photo after the other. But it never redirects to `/showphoto`.

It was working with Dancer(1) when I run the application just by `perl app.pl` from the bin directory. How I use Dancer2 und run it by using `plackup app.psgi`

I tried to put it into a before hook, but it changed nothing.

---

Update:

I figured out a way to work around this issue.

First I refactored my code a bit. Basic idea was to split the take photo and show photo operations into two different routes. This makes it easier to see what happens.

```
get '/takesinglephoto' => sub {

    my $photo;


    $photo = takePicture();
    $single_photo=$photo;

    redirect '/showsinglephoto';

;

get '/showsinglephoto' => sub {

    set 'layout' => 'fotobox-main';
    template 'fotobox_fotostrip',
        {
            'foto_filename' => $single_photo,
            'redirect_uri' => "fotostrip",
            'timer' => $timer,
            'number' => 'blank'
        };

};
```

And I moved the `takePicture` method just into my Dancer main `App.pm`.

Now I recognized from the log output, that the browser does not load the '/takesinglephoto' page once, but refreshes it every some secons. I think the reason is, that `takePicture()` takes some seconds to run and to return the output. And Dancer does not wait until it ends. With every reload, it triggers the `takePicture()` again and that causes the infinite-loop.

I worked around this by implementing a simple check to run `takePicture()` just once.

```
# define avariable set to 1 / true
my $do_stuff_once = 1;

get '/takesinglephoto' => sub {

    my $photo;

    # check if variable is true
    if ($do_stuff_once == 1) {
      $photo = takePicture();
      $single_photo=$photo;
      # set variable to false
      $do_stuff_once = 0;
    }

    redirect '/showsinglephoto';

};

get '/showsinglephoto' => sub {

    # set variable back to true
    $do_stuff_once = 1;
    set 'layout' => 'fotobox-main';
    template 'fotobox_fotostrip',
        {
            'foto_filename' => $single_photo,
            'redirect_uri' => "fotostrip",
            'timer' => $timer,
            'number' => 'blank'
        };

};
```

Now it still refreshes `/takesinglephoto`, but it does not trigger `takePicture()` again and again and finally, when the method returns the photo filename, it redirects to `/showsinglephoto`.

I would call this a workaround. Is there a better way to solve this?

BR
Arne

Comment: Do you need the `$photobox` model to be only there once, or can it be instantiated in every request? Try moving it into a plugin. See plugins like the ones for DBIx::Class or Redis for examples.

Comment: If you show us some more of your Photobox magic, maybe manage to reproduce the problem in your example scope, I'll try to help debug it.

Comment: And you probably want to look at the log in _trace_ mode to see what's going on.

Comment: You are passing the redirect url to the template. You are not redirecting in this code. If you want to actually do a redirect why not call `redirect` ?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @simbabque I've added details about the takePicture Method I'm calling.

Comment: @bytepusher I'm passing the URL because I do not want to redirect immediately, but after some seconds. /photo is to show the photo. So it supposes so first take the picture and then show it. The template will then redirect to the next page. Showphoto in my example is a bit irritating. I've changed it.

Comment: Ok, I doubt it has anything to do with the Photobox module. I would still make the declaration either into the route handler and have it lexical there so you get a new one every time, or if that doesn't have state, turn it into a plugin. We need to see some log output, the headers of the response you get in the browser, and the template where you do the redirect please.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque. I'll see what I can get out of the log. Might take some days until I'll find time to work on my booth again.

Comment: Hi all. I edited by question and added a workaround. I think the issues is caused, because `takePicture()`takes some time to run and Dancer / the browser does not wait. See my edit for details. Thanks, Arne

Comment: You need to ping people directly for them to get a notification. You can only @ mention one user per comment. I came and checked back here by myself.